# What does the std::list do with its allocator argument?

Tags: c++, stl

`std::list` is parameterized by an allocator type, which it presumably rebinds in order to allocate list nodes rather than `T`s. So what does it do with the object of allocator type passed to the constructor?

```
template <class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class list
{
    class node { ... T element; ... };

    using real_alloc =
        typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<node>;
    real_alloc m_allocator;

public:
    list(const Alloc&);
};
```

In the above code, we need to initialize `m_allocator` to a node allocator, but the constructor is given a `T` allocator. Do we just drop the `T` allocator on the floor, or do we use it somehow?

Answer (score 4):

Since `C++11` allocators can be stateful. You want to construct your internal allocator using the user supplied one. An [Allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) is explicitely required to be constructible from `typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<U>`.

Implementations of list constructor should look like this:

```
template<class T, class Alloc>
class list
{
      struct node_type {/*etc*/}; //internal
      using allocator_type_internal = typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::template rebind_alloc<node_type>;
      // etc.
      allocator_type_internal m_allocator; //Note we use allocator_type, not Alloc.
};

list::list(const Alloc& alloc ) : 
     m_allocator(alloc)
{ /* initialize sentinel node, etc. */ }
```

Although a good implementation would use empty-base optimization for the allocator.

Answer (score 2):

The `T` allocator is still used to `construct()` and `destroy()` the `T` portion of the internal nodes. Using these operations may be necessary to add custom arguments during construction, e.g., optionally forward a suitable allocator argument to the constructed objects.